# Can't use "this" as an argument in the getLoaderManager().initLoader() method

Tags: android, search, android-loadermanager

Instead of using some of the deprecated SimpleCursorAdapter constructors, many people have suggested to use LoaderManager and CursorLoader. So when calling getLoaderManager().initLoader() it gives me this error:

The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, SearchResultsActivity)

I have tried importing the v4 version of the loadermanager and cursorloader, but that has not seem to work. I have also tried the getSupportLoaderManager(), which doesn't work as well. I noticed that some people are getting this error and have looked through the conversation to try and find solutions, but the ones I have found don't work. I am calling the LoaderManager within the showResults() method btw

Code for searchable activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
public class SearchResultsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ListView list;
DatabaseTable db;
LoaderManager lm;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    db = new DatabaseTable(this);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
     if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }

}

private void showResults(String query) {
    db = new DatabaseTable(this);
    Cursor cursor = db.getContactMatches(query, null);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            null, new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactActivity.class);
            contactIntent.setData(getIntent().getData());
            startActivity(contactIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

 // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;

}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) however your question is likely to get closed/downvoted due to absence of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and for putting in a code dump and expect others to read it is frowned upon. Can you show us the relevant snippet and what was the logcat and what have you tried? :)

Comment: Sorry for that, but in one of my previous posts, someone told to post my entire code. I'll remember to post in snippets.

Comment: Actually Sam has solved my problem, so thanks for asking anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method `initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)` in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments `(int, null, SearchResultsActivity)`

Simply put: `SearchResultsActivity` *must* implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`. Otherwise `this` doesn't refer to an instance of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`...

Comment: I also have another question..... When I execute the code after adding LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks to my class deceleration and I search my database for the contact name by giving it a query, nothing actually shows up in my ListView. Does anyone think it is because my cursor is null?

Comment: Does the search feature actually call [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)? Use a LogCat statement or your debugger to see. `onNewIntent()` only works in very limited circumstances.

Comment: I'll check to see if that is the problem

Comment: I think the error is coming because I didn't set the id to android.R.layout.simple_list_item1 to the layout I wanted to show my results.

Comment: Hmm, your SimpleCursorAdapter above looks fine as long as you load a Cursor eventually. However this is a very different question from what you originally asked. Please click the check mark to accept this answer as the solution since it helped you. Then post a _new_ question with the relevant code, the logcat, and an explanation of what is happening. Good luck!

Comment: It's funny how some users tell me to just add on to my post instead of posting a new question.

Comment: Yeah, you'll never please everyone. We all think we are right, even though we all believe different things. :) Anyway, if there is a substantial change in your code between each question, it helps prove that you have made a lot of effort to solve the problem yourself. If you post multiple questions within 10 minutes, or even a few hours, it's likely that you have given the problem a serious effort. Some of us have been stuck on one problem for months or years... So when I read "I have spent the last few hours searching _everywhere!_" I don't believe it. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you must implement your class with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
and then you can use "this" keyword in initLoader method (remember that support library is deprecated and you use `LoaderManager.getInstance(this)` instead of `getLoaderManager()`